# How to make uiimageview circle.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cornerradius

I need to make UIImageView in circle radius, I am using this block of code for this taks.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self performSelector:@selector(setStyleCircleForImage:) withObject:_imageview afterDelay:0];

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}

-(void) setStyleCircleForImage:(UIImageView *)imgView {

    imgView.layer.cornerRadius = _imageview.frame.size.height / 2.0;
    imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

> Its working perfect in iOS 5 but when test in other device it shape is change I don't know why it happens. Please make some help.

Comment: Two rules
1. The width and height of the component should be same.
2. In your case the frame might not be updated, try put in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` it should work.

Comment: ok sir i tried to implement it

Comment: imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.width / 2.0; try this

Comment: @iphonic if i make width and height of uiimageview same its work but goes differ on other device

Comment: is there any probelm in your code

Comment: no sir its working fine now. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use mask to make circle like this function

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self makeCircleImage: _imageview];
 }

  -(void)makeCircleImage:(UIImageView *)img{
      CGFloat img_width = img.bounds.size.width;
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(img_width,img_width), NO, 0);
      CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
      CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
      CGContextFillEllipseInRect(c, CGRectMake(0,0,img_width,img_width));
      UIImage* maskim = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

      CALayer* mask = [CALayer new];
      mask.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,img_width,img_width);
      mask.contents = (id)maskim.CGImage;

      img.layer.mask = mask;
  }
```

Comment: how will i correlate between my image name this method?

Comment: yes sir its working in iPhone 6s plus let me check some other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourImageView.frame.size.width/2;
 yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: yes. you have to add in viewDidLoad. Why are you using Selectror?

Comment: @sandeeptomar you have to use `masksToBounds ` insted of `clipsToBounds `

Comment: ok sir and what is  _imgFriendsPhoto in your code. will it by image name?

Comment: @sandeeptomar have you tryed?

Comment: yes sir but its create same thing, whenever i test on iPhone 5 it working but if i tested some other device , its not appearing circle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110094/discussion-between-vvk-and-sandeep-tomar).

Answer (score 0):

First give `equal width` and `equal height` for `UIImageView`, then make use it

```
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.height / 2.0;

imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I resolve my issue by the answer of EI Captain. Thanks for support sir